# Use of HTML 5 doctype creates a gap at top of page on iphone safari browser

Tags: iphone, html

**Update:** Please disregard, my problem was caused by an advertisement bar being inserted by the vendor who provides my workplace wireless service.

I was building a mobile friendly website and wanted to use HTML 5. However when I specify the doctype as `<!DOCTYPE HTML>` , I get a gap at the top of the page on safari on the iphone.

I notice that other sites have the same problem such as nextstop.com and nike.com

I guess safari does not fully support HTML 5 yet. Anybody know of a workaround?

Comment: I am not seeing a gap with any HTML5 sites on my iPhone, nor on nike.com. Perhaps it is down to default browser CSS?

Comment: What iphone do you have? I'm using a 3rd gen ipod touch.

Comment: That's odd. I'm also running 3.1.2.

Comment: My problem was caused by an advertisement bar being inserted by the vendor who provides my workplace wireless service.

Answer (score 1):

HTML 5 is still in a very unstable state. Don't use it in a production environment.

**Edit** Just so you guys know what it's about, [HTML 5 is currently an *Editor's Draft*](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html), and the document clearly states (in the *Status of This Document* section) that *this specification is not stable*, and that a consensus may not have been reached on any of the proposed sections. I think it should be clear enough that it means it's a bit early to start using it.

Comment: Thanks zneak. I realize it is still a draft but it looks like a good number of sites are moving ahead and using it. It all depends on the project and requirements but I was going to and use html5 for some personal projects.

Answer (score 0):

All browsers correctly interpret the HTML doctype. Putting it in sets your browser into Standards Compliant mode, that is the only difference with or without the doctype.

You can use a CSS reset tool like http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ to get rid of default margins and padding on all elements.